# Run a batch file at folder's context menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, explorer

I'd like to run this batch file (setenv.cmd) when I right click on any folder:

```
@echo off
SET CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\mingw32\include;C:\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include;
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Archivos de programa\7-Zip;C:\Archivos de programa\WinRAR;C:\usr\bin;C:\msys\1.0\bin;C:\gtk2\bin
SET PKG_CONFIG_PATH=C:\gtk2\lib\pkgconfig;C:\usr\lib\pkgconfig
@echo on
```

I setuped my registry from [this page](http://www.burgaud.com/open-command-window-here/), with the "prompt here". My question is how to open the console window from the selected directory and run my batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&`. On Windows 8.1:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdDD]
@="CMD + setenv"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdDD\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\"&call \"D:\\full\\path\\to\\setenv.cmd\" \"%V\""

;
```

Note that all inner `"` double quotes and `\` reverse slashes in the data are *escaped* with a `\` backslash. In fact, data are as follows:

```
==>reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdDD\command

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdDD\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"&call "D:\full\path\to\setenv.cmd" "%V"
```

**Edit**: `cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"&call "D:\full\path\to\setenv.cmd"` should suffice. An additional (trailing) `"%V"` is merely a remainder residue of *my* debugging practice (`@echo %1` in the batch to ensure it works).

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`&` special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: What is `%V` going to be expended to? is this Windows-8-specific?

Comment: @aschipfl I don't think so. Long-ago, I ran some own tests in Windows  (`XP` if I can remember). [Confirmed here nowadays](http://superuser.com/a/473602/376602).

Comment: I was not aware of that, thank you! I don't understand the description _"for verbs that are none implies all"_ in the linked post - do you know what that means?

Comment: @aschipfl Honestly, I don't know exact meaning, not being a native English… However, it works as described in my answer. The OP Juze was asked for unsuccessfuly…