# Invoking cmake from Contextual menu

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, cmd

In my work I use to invoke a lot of times cmake, building MSVS solutions. Each time I need to open a cmd line window and call cmake on my sources. I managed to create an alias to only write **"cm ../source"**, which calls **"cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" ../source"**.

I'd like to improve this process by adding an entry in the explorer's contextual menu.
I do not manage, only at once to call cmd.exe and execute **"cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" ../source"** or whatever : "cm ../source"

I read [this very usefull topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420410/run-a-batch-file-at-folders-context-menu)

but I don't manage to pass arguments to cmd.exe and execute them :

This doesn't work:

```
cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"call "cm ../source"  "%V"
```

Then I tried to execute a cmd file, and I manage to do it, but it's like to line  inside wasn't executed and I don't understand why. My entry in the registry is :

```
cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"&call ".\cmake.cmd"
```

It correctly calls cmake.cmd (local file in my build directory) file which only contains:

[image: cmake.cmd content]

and this executes the cmd file in an infinite loop that I don't understand :

[image]

My questions are :

- Why this infinite loop. It acts like the file content wasn't executed.
- Is there a better way to do without calling a separate file. I'd like to only invoke cmake without having this cmd file.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: So `cmake` is a batch file? I'm not sure but the following could work: `cmd.exe /S /K pushd "%V" ^& call cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" "%V"` (perhaps the `^` is not necessary)...

Comment: you do something wrong. CMake is not supposed to be run manually each time you update the project files, there are actually very few cases when you should do that. And if you do programming get used to keep a console open, maybe even with several tabs.

Comment: Slava : I don' do that so often but I still want to find out how to do.
@aschipfl : I tried with the start command : cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V" &start cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" ../source  "%V", it gives the same result as if I call my cmake.cmd file : infinite loop.